# Change only one span to input inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple app, that shows tasks. I would like to double click on a task to edit it, so I want it change from `<span>` to `<input type="text" />`. Here's my code:

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="task.done" ng-click="taskDone(task.id, !task.done)"/>
    <span ng-dblclick="editTask()" ng-if="!editable">{{::task.task}}</span>
    <input type="text" ng-if="editable" value="{{task.task}}" />
</li>
```

But when I double click on a task, every `<span>` changes to `<input type="text" />`:

[image]

Here's that directive that generates the HTML code:

```
export const tasksList = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            tasks: "="
        },
        templateUrl: '../dist/views/tasksList.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watchCollection('tasks', function(tasks) {
                scope.updateTasks();
            });
        },
        controller: function($scope) {
            const self = this;
            $scope.editable = false;
            $scope.editTask = function() {
                $scope.editable = true;
            };
            $scope.updateTasks = function() {
                self.tasks = $scope.tasks;
            };
            $scope.taskDone = function(id, taskDone) {
                $scope.tasks[id].done = taskDone;
            };
        },
        controllerAs: "$ctrl"
    };
};
```

How can I change only one `<span>` to `<input type="text" />`?

Comment: Show your js please

Comment: It would be easier if you'll provide some code..

Comment: Bind all the `editable` attributes to the `$index` or the id of the task.

Comment: @thepio what do you mean by `bind`?

Comment: @AdrianWydmanski well one way is to do what Thor Jacobsen has in his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting the `editable` flag on the task, and not the scope.

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="task.done" ng-click="taskDone(task.id, !task.done)"/>
    <span ng-dblclick="editTask(task)" ng-if="!task.editable">{{::task.task}}</span>
    <input type="text" ng-if="task.editable" value="{{task.task}}" />
</li>

...
$scope.editTask = function(task) {
     task.editable = true;
 };
...
```